# Filter consecutive identical values if at start or end of unique id

Tags: r, select, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset with GPS locations of birds doing multiple trips from a colony. I want to remove all points within 3 km from the colony, but ONLY those that are at the beginning or the end of an individual trip (Unique_id). If they come to within 3 km of the colony in the middle of a trip, and then head off again without returning to the colony first, I want to retain these points.

I calculated the distance to the colony and then defined using a logical column whether the location was < 3km (1) or > 3km (0). With the coordinates removed, the dataframe looks a bit like the below dummy data. So from here, I am looking to define something along the lines of "remove rows with dist3k == 1 for the first or last consecutive "1"s of a Unique_id.

Hope this makes sense, and look forward to suggestions.

```
# what the data looks like 
data_orig <- data.frame(
  Index = rep(c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10',
                '11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20')),
  Unique_id = rep(c('A1','A2'), each = 10),
  dist3k = rep(c('1','1','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','1','0','1','0','1','1')))

# what I want the output to be 
data_new <-data_orig[-c(1,2,10,11,12,13,19,20),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `cumsum`.

It works by inverting the binary values `dist3k!=1` and then calculating the cumulative sum `cumsum(dist3k!=1)`, which is always zero in the beginning when the vector starts with 1.

Then for the last values the same is done but in reverse.

We now have two vectors `fil1` and `fil2` where we can filter looking for non-zero values.

```
library(dplyr)

data_orig %>% 
  group_by(Unique_id) %>% 
  mutate(fil1=cumsum(dist3k!=1), fil2=rev(cumsum(rev(dist3k)!=1))) %>% 
  filter(fil1!=0 & fil2!=0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-starts_with("fil"))
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   Index Unique_id dist3k
   <chr> <chr>     <chr> 
 1 3     A1        0     
 2 4     A1        0     
 3 5     A1        0     
 4 6     A1        1     
 5 7     A1        1     
 6 8     A1        0     
 7 9     A1        0     
 8 14    A2        0     
 9 15    A2        1     
10 16    A2        0     
11 17    A2        1     
12 18    A2        0
```

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for your post - I get an error running this code:

Error in filter.default(., fil1 != 0, fil2 != 0) : 
  object 'fil2' not found... do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: @user303287 I made a small change, added an ampersand in the filter rule. Maybe it's a version problem.

Comment: That works perfectly!! Thank you so much. Would you mind explaining what the code does?

Comment: Wow. what a creative mind you have! Thanks for explaining.